# how to use EmbedCode[CloudDeploy[Manipulate[...]]]

Tags: cloud-deploy

This is a question about `EmbedCode[CloudDeploy[...]]`. I have seen various questions and answers about the similar questions, but none of them helped me in embedding several `Manipulate`s on my own website. After embedding a Manipulate, I refresh my website. It works with Firefox browser. My questions are twofold:

1. Interactivity is fine on my computer, but I cannot change the font size in Manipulate. How can I adjust font size and shrink the Manipulate window size?
2. Although deployment works on my computer, it does not work on other people's computers, the `Starting Interactivity` command never starts. How can I get it to work on the computers of others? My intention is to make Manipulate publicly available with interactivity function.

Here is the code I use:

```
f[n_]:=n^2+1;
Manipulate[f[n], {n,1,10}]//EmbedCode[
CloudDeploy[#, Permissions -> {All -> {"Read", "Interact"}}], 
ImageSize -> {50, 80} + ImageDimensions@Rasterize@#] &
```

**Additional Question**

I am confused with scattered information on how to embed a notebook to my webpage. The following link gives some information, but I am not sure if this information is still valid to embed a notebook into a webpage. If so, why do we have various different methods for embedding, and which one is the best for someone who does not know much about programming. I can see that embedding a `Manipulate` output and a `Notebook` itself are treated differently.

https://reference.wolfram.com/language/WolframNotebookEmbedder/docs/GettingStarted/